# Proof validation: dense spaces of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $L^2_x([0,1])$ be the space $\{ f : \int_0^1 x|f(x)|^2\,dx < \infty\}$ with the scalar product $$[f, g] := \int_0^1 x [f(x)]^*g(x)\,dx,$$
where $f^*$ is the complex conjugate of $f$.
I'm asked to show that in this space $L^2([0,1])$ is $\|\cdot\|_{L^2_x([0,1])}$- dense.

---

Here is how I proceed. 
I'll denote with $\|\cdot\|_x$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ the norms $\|\cdot\|_{L^2_x([0,1])}$ and $\|\cdot|_{L^2([0,1])}$, respectively.

> For any $f \in L^2_x([0,1])$ let $g$ be a function in $L^2([0,1])$. 
>   Due to the density of $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$ in $L^2([0,1])$ we have:
>   $$\forall \varepsilon > 0,\; \forall g \in L^2([0,1]) \;\; \exists h \in \mathcal{C}^0([0,1]) \;/\; \|g-h\|_2 \leq \varepsilon; $$
>   therefore, for the $g$ previously taken (for every $f$), it is:
>   $$\|f-g\|_x = \|f-h + (h - g)\|_x \leq \|f-h\|_x + \|h-g\|_x \leq \|f-h\|_x + \|h-g\|_2,$$
>   being $\ x|\varphi(x)|^2 \leq |\varphi(x)|^2 \ \forall x \in [0,1]$, and so: 
>   $$\|f-g\|_x \leq \|f-h\|_x + \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
>   For the first of the two terms on the right we have:
>   $$\|f(x)-h(x)\|_x \equiv \int_0^1 x|f(x)-h(x)|^2\,dx = \int_0^1 \left|\sqrt x f(x) - \sqrt x h(x)\right|^2\,dx = \\ \|\sqrt x f(x) - \sqrt x h(x)\|_2;$$
>   moreover: 
>   $$f(x) \in L^2_x([0,1]) \; \Rightarrow  \; \sqrt x f(x) \in L^2([0,1]),$$
>   and therefore the density of $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$ in $L^2([0,1])$ can be used again **to assert that** it is $\|f-h\|_x \leq \varepsilon/2$ and to conclude the proof.

My concern is about the fact that the function $\sqrt x h(x)$ chosen in the second application of the density argument is somewhat dependent on $g$; nevertheless, on the other side, $g$ depends on $f$... So, is this proof invalidated by those relations of dependency (in particular, by the first one)?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: you say "completeness" but i guess what you mean is "density", right ?

Comment: Just a minor technical point here but $L^{2}([0,1])$ is the *completion* of $C([0,1])$. However, that isn't to say that $C([0,1])$ is complete in $L^{2}([0,1])$ since the limit functions are not continuous themselves. Like Renart said, the correct phrasing would be $C([0,1])$ is *dense* in $L^{2}([0,1])$.

Comment: @Wavelet, you're right. I'm sorry, I was translating from Italian and I focused more on the symbolism than on the language. Thanks, I've fixed it.

Comment: @Renart as I've said above, you're right. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat simpler argument: Let $f \in L^2_x$ and let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Using the dominated convergence theorem, there exists small enough $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
                      \int_{0}^{\delta}x|f(x)|^2dx < \epsilon^2
$$
Then $f_{\delta}=\chi_{[\delta,1]}f$ is in $L^2$ because
$$
            \int_{\delta}^{1}|f(x)|^2 \le \frac{1}{\delta}\int_{\delta}^{1}x|f(x)|^2dx < \infty.
$$
A quick check shows $\|f-f_{\delta}\|_{L^2_{x}} < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, this is a much more elegant proof. Anyway can I ask you if the passage I've highlighted in my post is vicious or not?